# printf a double with significant figures without scientific notation

Tags: objective-c, string-formatting

I'd like to use a printf-style format string in

```
+ stringWithFormat:
```

to convert a double into a string with 2 significant figures but no scientific notation. %.2g uses scientific notation and %.2f restricts to digits after decimal instead of significant figures. I'd like 0.000232 to become "0.00023", not "0.00" or "3.4e-2".
Is this possible?

Comment: Did you take a look at `NSNumberFormatter`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this code block will solve your problem.

```
NSNumberFormatter *format = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[format setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[format setMaximumSignificantDigits:2];
NSNumber *numb = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.000232];
NSString *txt = [format stringFromNumber:numb];
NSLog(@"%@",txt);
```

I created a formatter with decimal style numbering and set its significant digits to 2. You can change maximum significant digits to suit your needs. I hope it helps.